# Designing a TCP/IP command interface for a robot

Tags: python, tcp, client-server

**Introduction**

I am working on a robotic sampling application. Each robot has a cabled interface with power, TCP/IP and a gas-sensor tubing. The robots are on an ARM platform, and I intend to do most of the programming in Python. The robots move slowly and there is nothing computationally intensive running on them.

Each robot should perform these "services":

- Move left/right (for manual control)
- Move up/down    (for manual control)
- Go to next sector

Each robot report these sensor readings or events:

- Temperature
- End-switch right
- Docked at sector with ID: ###
- Encoder count [lateral,longitudinal]
- Error event

**Client - Server Architecture**

I view each robot as a client, and the sensor hub computer as the server.
The server will have a known ip and listening port, and allow the robots to connect.
The server will do the measurement scheduling, and command the robots to move from sector to sector.

The server may maintain and update a model of each robot with a state-vector containing:

`[ position, switches, sensor-readings, status]`

**Questions**

From debugging serial communication, I have experienced the benefits of having a human readable communication interface with a strict poll-response structure. I am however not sure how we should go forth designing this interface.

- Are there any best practices in designing communication interfaces for devices like these?
- Should I think about packet loss and corruption, or is this fully handled by TCP?
- Should I design everything as services polled by the server, or should the robots broadcast it's sensor readings and events?
- Should I implement *Acknowledgment* of commands, e.g. *go-to-next-section*

I apologize for the broad and vague problem formulation, this may be more a philosophy question than a software problem. However I will greatly appreciate your thoughts, experiences and advice.

**TLDR**

What are the guiding principles of designing TCP communication protocols for client-server architectures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall Id suggest using python Twisted to build your server and client (robot side) applications (https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/). Anyways to answer your question:

*"Are there any best practices in designing communication interfaces for devices like these?"*

See answers to your other questions bellow.

*"Should I think about packet loss and corruption, or is this fully handled by TCP?"*

TCP guarantees the integrity of the data you are getting. The primary things to worry about is if the client/servers are connected or not. You can use a ReconnectingClientProtocol to make your connections a little more robust when server is restarted (see Twisted specs). Also be aware that TCP is a streaming protocol (you may not get the whole message at once), so make sure you got the whole message before acting on it. If you are sending messages quickly you may also have more than one message in your TCP buffer for that client.

*"Should I design everything as services polled by the server, or should the robots broadcast it's sensor readings and events?"*

Avoid polling. When the robots start up they should establish a persistent TCP connection with the server. Messages should be sent and received (handled) asynchronously.

*"Should I implement Acknowledgment of commands, e.g. go-to-next-section"*

Wouldn't hurt. Would be good for flow control within your application as well as recovering from situations where the server or robots are restarted and you can't be sure whether a message was processed or not.

*"What are the guiding principles of designing TCP communication protocols for client-server architectures?"*

Probably the thing to do for your app is to design a simple command response protocol. Start by designing simple message sets, on going from client to server, the other from server to client. You could use simple human readable XML message set as follows:

Server to Client

> ```
> <SCMessage type="TurnRight"></SCMessage>
> <SCMessage type="TurnLeft"></SCMessage>
> <SCMessage type="NextSector"><param key="sectorName" value="B"/></SCMessage>
> <SCMessage type="GetStatus"></SCMessage>
> <SCMessage type="Ack"></SCMessage>
> ```

Client to Server

> ```
> <SCMessage type="SensorUpdate"><param key="data" value="123"/></SCMessage>
> <SCMessage type="StatusChanged"><param key="status" value="Good"/></SCMessage>
> ....
> <SCMessage type="Ack"></SCMessage>
> ```

So when parsing these messages you can teas them apart by looking for the SCMessage start stop tags. Once you have a message you could then use an XML parser to parse the messages contents. Alternatively you could use JSON which would actually probably be a lot easier (basically you'd be sending little dictionaries back and forth).

You've got a lot of reading to-do ;) Id start by reading up on python Twisted a bit and make little toy programs to get comfortable with things.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Ron. This is more than I had hoped for from such a general question. I'll try to post a bit of a follow-up as I get to implement a prototype.